# use of infinitive in a sentence where the subject is unchanged

Tags: grammaire, expressions, choix-de-mot, ordre-des-mots, infinitif

Since he made an effort to speak to me, I thought I should at least know his name.

'Puisqu'il a fait un effort de me parler, je croyais au moins devoir savoir son nom'

I am wondering if:
a) I have used 'devoir' correctly since the subject of the sentence is still 'Je/I' and would therefore have no need to say 'Je croyais que ... je dois/devrais...'
b) 'faire un effort' is the correct idiomatic equivalent of 'making an effort.'
c) The adverb 'au moins' is correctly positioned in the sentence

Comment: Use in this case "pour le moins" instead of "au moins"; check why here: http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?11;s=3860453160;r=1;nat=;sol=0;

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is correct, but heavy: the action is a chain of 3 verbs: croire, devoir, savoir. 
You might have rather turned it this way:

```
Puisqu'il a fait l'effort de me parler, je me suis fait un devoir de connaitre son nom.
```

Answer (score 0):

a) It is hard to use the infinive *devoir* here.

b) yes

c) yes

---

*Je croyais au moins devoir savoir son nom* won't be understood.

Here is an idiomatic way to say it:

> *Puisqu'il **avait** fait **l**'effort de me parler, je me suis dit qu'il me fallait au moins connaître son nom.*

or

> *..., je me suis dit que je devais au moins apprendre son nom.*

Comment: Thanks. Just to confirm, is the issue with the use of the infinitive form of 'devoir' that the meaning is ambiguous, in that it is unclear whether it denotes a necessity (dois/devais) or a recommendation (devrais)?

Comment: Yes, using *devoir savoir* would be confusing here for being ambiguous.